# Angular JS How to check if added word already exists

Tags: angularjs

How do I check if an added word already exists, no matter of case?
Check about case sensitive, and then if yes then it already exists?

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["BMW", "AUDI", "BENTLY"];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.addMe) {return;}  


        if ($scope.products.lastIndexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) 
        {

            $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
        } 
        else {
            $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your shopping list.";
        }
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        $scope.errortext = "";    
        $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

function you need is:

```
 function isAddedToList(item) {
   $scope.products.forEach(function(product){
       if(item === product){
          return true;
       }
   });
 }
```